# xcode provision profile problem

Tags: iphone, xcode

Today, i encountered a problem. Xcode worked fine with my iphone4 device and provision code. But today i updated itunes. After that xcode can't connect device. Everything looks right but xcode can't connect the device. note: I reinstalled cert and provision four times.

Comment: Did you use Xcode Organizer tool to delete and replace the provisioning profile on your device?

Comment: Does the Organizer detect your device and Xcode not or both don't detect it ?

Comment: Yes kl94, organizer detect device and xcode not.

Comment: http://d.pr/jkyu screenshot was in url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look to the deployment target (in the project setting AND in the target setting. If your iOS device version is lower than your deployment target , then Xcode won't detect your device.